# SQL Server Select ID from table 1 where all ID in table2 match criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table1                                 Table2

requestID  requestComplete             requestID   DocumnentNum DocumentComplete
1           0                             1            ABC             1
2           1                             1            DEF             1
3           0                             1            GHI             1
4           0                             2            XXX             1
5           1                             3            YYY             0
```

My question is this: how do I find `requestID`'s from table one where `requestComplete = 0` and all the documents for that `requestID` in table2 have `documentCompleted = 1`?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Is it possible that there wouldn't be any records in Table2 for the particular request?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.requestID
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.requestID = t2.requestID
where t1.requestComplete = 0
group by t1.requestID
having sum(case when documentCompleted <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.requestID
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE t1.requestID = t2.requestID
AND t2.DocumentComplete = 0 
) AND t1.requestComplete = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

should work like:

```
SELECT T1.*
  FROM Table1 T1
 WHERE T1.requestComplete = 0
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM Table2 T2
                    WHERE T2.requestID = T1.requestID
                      AND T2.DocumentComplete != 1)
```

Comment: "!=" is T-SQL only, this is a better to stick the multi platform [ANSI 99 SQL standard](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf) and use "<>" instead. Although they both work under SQL Server and both give the same result, plus "<>" chars are closer to each other on the keyboard :)

Answer (score 0):

If T2.DocumentComplete is of a numeric datatype you can do something like this.

```
SELECT t1.RequestID, t1.RequestComplete, t2.MinDoc
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT t2.RequestID, MIN(t2.DocumentComplete) AS MinDoc
      FROM Table2 t2
      GROUP BY t2.RequestID
      HAVING MIN(t2.DocumentComplete) = 1) t2 ON t1.RequestID = t2.Requestid
WHERE t1.RequestComplete = 0
```

If it is not then you could just convert the t2.documentcomplete to INT. It would look like this.

```
SELECT t1.RequestID, t1.RequestComplete, t2.MinDoc
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT t2.RequestID, MIN(CONVERT(INT,t2.DocumentComplete)) AS MinDoc
      FROM Table2 t2
      GROUP BY t2.RequestID
      HAVING MIN(CONVERT(INT,t2.DocumentComplete)) = 1) t2 ON t1.RequestID = 
t2.Requestid
WHERE t1.RequestComplete = 0
```